# How to set the object pool manager properties in WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, pool

I created an object pool manager under `Resources > Object pool managers` in `WebSphere Application Server 7.0`. How do I set the `maxSize` and `minSize` of the pool? Can you direct me to a tutorial on how to set the properties of the pool? Also do you know of a website that list the properties that I can set?

I tried to search for it but I wasn't able to find it. Maybe I'm using the wrong keyword.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectPool implementation does not expose a mechanism for maximum pool size.  The mechanism is somewhat primitive, and you might be better off writing your own.  You might consider writing your own CustomObjectPool implementation, which would allow you to specify custom properties from the console.